# How to track down why apache2 processes are up for 45min / 1 hour or worse? NOT hosting, it's self managed VPS

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, process

I have a self managed VPS that I inherited from a previous administrator inside my Company, with lots of Wordpress websites running on it. The VPS has 2 CPUs, 6Gb or RAM and runs Ubuntu 10.04 64bit.

I noticed that the server was slow, very slow at times. So I used `top` command to check what was running and found out that there were many apache2 services who had been running for long times, up to 60 minutes, in some occasions. CPU and Memory usage to the roof.

The apache2 processes often run for too long - from 4 minutes to 8, 15, 30, 45 or even one hour, clogging CPU and Memory and basically killing everything.

- I drastically lowered the number of MaxClients
- I took out all the apache modules, one by one, and kept the ones needed to keep the website up
- I protected all the applications with spam and http requests filters

Nothing really changed.

How can I track down where the problem is coming from? All our wordpress are secure, both with denial of unexpected requests and secure non standard login pages and bot automatic blocking.

I want to track the problem down and fix it, so that the VPS will run smoothly.

This is the result of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
109.228.21.231:80      is a NameVirtualHost
default server server109-228-21-231.live-servers.net (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/ip_default/server109-228-21-231.live-servers.net.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost server109-228-21-231.live-servers.net (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/ip_default/server109-228-21-231.live-servers.net.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost default (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:67)
port 80 namevhost lists (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:139)
port 80 namevhost atmail.webmail (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/atmail.conf:9)
port 80 namevhost horde.webmail (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/horde.conf:9)
port 80 namevhost accessaa.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/accessaa.co.uk.conf:112)
port 80 namevhost bighandmedia.org (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/bighandmedia.org.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost c-mw.net (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/c-mw.net.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost centralexhibitioncentres.org (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/centralexhibitioncentres.org.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost conference-news.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/conference-news.co.uk.conf:112)
port 80 namevhost engage-magazine.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/engage-magazine.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost exhibitingmagazine.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/exhibitingmagazine.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost exhibitionnews.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/exhibitionnews.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost exhibitionworld.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/exhibitionworld.co.uk.conf:124)
port 80 namevhost h2openmagazine.com (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/h2openmagazine.com.conf:103)
port 80 namevhost holdsworthevents.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/holdsworthevents.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost om-pa.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/om-pa.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost peoplepeoplemedia.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/peoplepeoplemedia.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost productivepr.org (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/productivepr.org.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost redpavementgroup.com (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/redpavementgroup.com.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost show-pro.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/show-pro.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost stgeorgeshalls.com (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/stgeorgeshalls.com.conf:76)
port 80 namevhost whitebook.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/whitebook.co.uk.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost www.redrecruitment.net (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/www.redrecruitment.net.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost exhibitionnewsawards.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/forwarding/exhibitionnewsawards.co.uk_httpd.conf:6)
109.228.21.231:443     is a NameVirtualHost
default server default-109_228_21_231 (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:103)
port 443 namevhost default-109_228_21_231 (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:103)
port 443 namevhost lists (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/server.conf:168)
port 443 namevhost atmail.webmail (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/atmail.conf:58)
port 443 namevhost horde.webmail (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/horde.conf:46)
port 443 namevhost accessaa.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/accessaa.co.uk.conf:10)
port 443 namevhost conference-news.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/conference-news.co.uk.conf:10)
port 443 namevhost exhibitionworld.co.uk (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/exhibitionworld.co.uk.conf:10)
port 443 namevhost h2openmagazine.com (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/h2openmagazine.com.conf:10)
port 443 namevhost stgeorgeshalls.com (/etc/apache2/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/stgeorgeshalls.com.conf:10)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
default server server109-228-21-231.live-servers.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
port 80 namevhost server109-228-21-231.live-servers.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: It's not hosting, it's a self managed VPS. I think that there is sufficient information, as far as my knowledge let me understand. If I were able to track everything on my own, I would not need the help of community, wouldn't I?

Comment: You haven't even clearly described the problem! What is crashing? How do you know? What log entries relate to the crash?

Comment: Isn't the sentence "The apache2 processes often run for too long - from 4 minutes to 8, 15, 30, 45 or even one hour, clogging CPU and Memory and basically killing everything." self explanatory? Ok.

I noticed that the server was slow, very slow at times. So I used `top` command to check what was running and found out that there were many apache2 services who had been running for long times, up to 60 minutes, in some occasions. CPU and Memory usage to the roof.

Comment: No, that's not self explanatory, and it's not at all clear. You should provide _specific_ data.

Comment: This is an ongoing problem, with different _specific_ results every day, but general identical problems. 20 or 25 processes, 28 or 48 minutes. All this doesn't really make any difference. Different specifics but same result: clogged server. Thankfully there's people who is able to understand the situation and provide guidance nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

To check what particular apache2 process is doing, use strace.
    `# strace -p <pid>`
Look at systemcalls and make your way.

Comment: An AWFUL lot of lstat commands there.

Comment: What is the path you see for the files in the lstat calls, check which host name is having most of those requests?

Comment: It's lots and lots of different pages on different websites we have

Comment: What MPM you use on Apache?

Comment: Also note that, to control maximum concurrent connections, in case of prefork, you need to set MaximumRequestWorkers to desired number.  To have your apache terminate the old or free processes, you need to set MaxSpareThreads number, if free processes goes above this number, apache will exist those process.  But it appears that your VPS is very busy, and apache keep serving the requests.  As you already mentioned, `strace -p pid` shows you lot of systemcalls, this indicates that current running apache process is serving the requests, that means, there is real traffic.

Comment: `apache2ctl -V`returns `Server MPM: Prefork`, `threaded: no` and `forked: yes (variable process count)`. I don't have any `MaximumRequestWorkers` inside my `apache2.conf`. 
By the way, jut as an example, right now I have lots apache2 processes that have been up for more than 4 minutes, up to 7 minutes. One that was up for 20 just died.

Comment: The behaviour is kind of usual, if you see that every process dies after 20 minutes, that means some parameter set which lets process to run for 20 minutes and then die.

Comment: So we can say that probably I just have too much traffic combined with too many wordpress applications for the VPS that we have? Still, we have 2 CPUs and 6Gb of RAM. And we hardly have more than 65k/75k visits per month...

Comment: What about MySQL database, is it on the same box?

Comment: Same server, yes. What should I check?

Comment: Wordpress uses MySQL as its database, since your server has too many sites, check `show processlist;` output from mysql cli and see if you have too many handing queries taking time to complete?